# ActionController caching not working in dev and test environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, actioncontroller, page-caching

I have this controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  caches_page :index

  def index
  end
end
```

and `action_controller.perform_caching` enabled for each in environment.

On production everything acts as expected, with the cached page being stored in public/cache/index.html but for dev and test the cached version of index.html is being regenerated on every request.

I'm using Rails 3.1.8

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `config.cache_classes` setting, I can't guarantee this will help, in dev mode rails will generally reload everything.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html